# Django REST: one PUT request to populate two models

Tags: python, django, rest

I have two models with exact same fields in them:

- person
- log

Essentially, on a PUT request to **person**, I would like to *also* make a POST-like behavior to **log**.

How would I do that?

Comment: Your question isn't clear. put your code to better understand what you want to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do that would be to override the `save()` method of one of the models so that an update on one of them would update the other.

Based on the names of your models, I suppose that `person` is the "real" model while `logs` is there to track any change on the objects. With this assumptions, you could do something like that:

```py
class Person(models.Model):
    # model fields

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        Logs.objects.update_or_create(**kwargs)
        super(Person, self).save()
```

That being said, without any code provided, I can't guess how you would find the `Log` instance related to the `Person` instance.

Comment: You are correct! Turns out it was that easy.